# CA certificate for .NET Maui

Tags: .net, certificate, maui, multiplatform

I know .NET Maui is multi.platform, which is very nice for unique code.
When thinking in deploy and publish the app we need to trust all the binaries, so that the user (client) will install your app without any "problem".

Here comes my question, do I either need individual certificate for each platform or there is some kind of multi-certificate that works for all?

In other words I want my app can installed in Android, Ios, Windows and MacOs without any workaround of "Click here and there to allow install from unstrusted sources" or "Just ignore the self-signed certificate message".